# What does component.get('v.recordId',value) do?

Tags: javascript, aura

I am reading a component and I found the following line:

```
component.get('v.recordId',accID);
```

I didn't know there was syntax like this what does it do ? I logged it and confirmed that it works, but I cant' find any docs that talk about `.get` with a second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely a typo or a copy-paste mistake. `get` only uses the first parameter, but it is not harmful to include a second parameter in JavaScript. You can try this in any flavor of JavaScript:

```
var f = function(x) { console.log(x); }
f(300, 500);
```

It is more likely that the developer intended:

```
component.set('v.recordId', accID);
```

Comment: Kinda what I thought thanks!